# How to fix the ElementNotVisibleException in Edge browser using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gwt, microsoft-edge

I am currently testing a GWT web application similar to MS Paint and the problem which I am facing is that my test case passes on the browsers like Chrome, Firefox, and IE but sadly, it fails in the Microsoft Edge browser. I am unable to find out how to fix this issue after searching the whole Internet and trying out many methods which are written on the Stack Overflow and Google Groups, I am feeling extremely hopeless. Meanwhile, here is my code:

```
public class Insert_Element_in_Edge {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void main() throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:\\SELENIUM\\Drivers\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.get("xxxx.com");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("xxxx"));
        WebElement canvas = driver.findElement(By.id("frontCanvas"));
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        final String InsertPath="//img[contains(@src,'Insert Element')]";
        WebElement Insert = driver.findElement(By.xpath(InsertPath));
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Insert.click();

    }
}
```

Here's the error which I am facing:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element not displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Given below is the HTML code of the element which I am trying to locate in the Edge browser.

```
<div id="isc_2Q" eventproxy="isc_XXXIconButton_SClient_1" role="button" aria-label="xxx"
    onfocus="isc.EH.handleFocus(isc_XXXIconButton_SClient_1,true);" 
    onblur="if(window.isc)isc.EH.handleBlur(isc_XXXIconButton_SClient_1,true);" 
    tabindex="1020" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 54px; width: 40px; 
    height: 34px; z-index: 201152; padding: 0px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible; 
    cursor: pointer;" onscroll="return isc_XXXIconButton_SClient_1.$lh()" class="iconHoverZindex">
    <div id="isc_2R" 
        eventproxy="isc_XXXIconButton_SClient_1" style="position: relative; 
        -webkit-margin-collapse: separate separate; visibility: inherit; 
        z-index: 201152; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer;">
        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="40px" height="34px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap="true" class="iconButton" style="background-color:transparent;"
                        align="center" valign="middle" onfocus="isc_XXXIconButton_SClient_1.$47()">
                        
                        <img src="Insert Element.png" width="24" height="24" align="TEXTTOPundefined" 
                            class="iconButtonHIcon" eventpart="icon" border="0" 
                            suppress="TRUE" draggable="true"/>
                         &nbsp;
                        <span style="vertical-align:middle;align-content:center;"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This element is visible in other 3 browsers and is clicked successfully. But I just got stuck in Edge. Also, in Edge, the HTML5 canvas is also not displayed using Selenium.  Please help.

Comment: Which of the elements fails here? Is it possible to post the website url or not?

Comment: Sorry i can't post the URL because of the policies of my company. The WebElement Insert is failing here.

Comment: Hmm. Can you maybe post part of the html? So I can create my own html file using that part and try it out locally.

Comment: I have added the HTML code in the question details. Please check.

Comment: Hmm. In that html part I can't find any of the elements you are trying to find. So this part of html wont work.

Comment: From the `HTML` you provided, I am unable to locate either of the elements i.e `By.id("frontCanvas")` as well as `//img[contains(@src,'Insert Element')]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB, sorry it was my mistake. I forgot to edit xxx.png to Insert Element.png because of the privacy policy of company.
Now, I have edited that, please check

Comment: @DG4 Currently when I'm using the new html. I can't find the frontCanvas part because it isn't in the html. So when I removed that part and continue with the test to search the webelement Insert, then it works here on my edge computer. I think we need the canvas part also. As i understand you are using html5 canvas and that might be the cause of your problems.

Comment: The element that you are trying to interact, is visible in edge browser while doing manually? What i think is it might be a bug and your application developer might work on.

Answer (score 0):

You can add wait statement before click on it as given below.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.xpath(InsertPath)));
```

Comment: I tried adding it and I was doing it the same way as you suggested but then it showed org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath

Comment: you can increase the time in wait

Comment: I tried increasing the timeout time but it didn't work for me. Can you suggest some other method?

Comment: try with actions class to click on it.

Comment: Tried it, still the same problem.

Comment: can you infer something from the HTML code of the element which I am trying to locate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use element to be clicable as it is a button

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 50);
final String InsertPath="//img[contains(@src,'Insert Element')]";
WebElement Insert= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(InsertPath)));
Insert.click();
```

Comment: So increase timeout time, it means your website take time to load

Comment: I tried increasing the timeout time but it didn't work for me. Can you suggest some other method?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I aslo had some trouble location elements with xPath in Edge, GWT and Selenium 
Sadly I didnt found a solution but a workaround:
We gave every Element an ID

for example:

```
panel.getElement().setId("panel-id");
```

and then used the ID-Locator to find the Element:

```
findElement(By.id("panel-id"))
```

Comment: Well, I want to know if these getElement() and setId() functions are associated with Selenium or GWT and if not, then how do I set the ID by myself because I haven't developed the GWT application and I am working on just the automation of that app.

Comment: Along with that, one thing which I think I forgot to mention is that when I check whether the EdgeDriver in Selenium is able to find the elements or not, then it was successfully able to find those elements but the real problem lies in the fact that they were not visible and thus, showing the exception.

Comment: @DG4 if you want to use getElement() and setId() these functions are part of the GWT code - When you are able to locate the WebElements but the click() fails and even if you wait for the Element to be Clickable - i would say its a weird bug with Edge and or Selinum/GWT

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few tweaks in your code block as follows:

1. First of all we will try to get rid of all the `Thread.sleep(n)` calls.
2. Now, to address the reason for `ElementNotVisibleException`, we will scroll the element of our interest within the [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and then invoke `click()` method.
3. Your final code block will may look:

   ```
   driver = new EdgeDriver();
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get("xxxx.com");
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("xxxx"));
   WebElement canvas = driver.findElement(By.id("frontCanvas"));
   WebElement Insert = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='isc_2R']//td/img[@class='iconButtonHIcon' and contains(@src,'Insert Element.png')]"));
   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", Insert); 
   Insert.click();
   ```

Comment: I tried your method and for the statement `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("frontCanvas")));` it is showing the TimeOut exception.

Comment: Edited the Answer, modified partial code as per your initial code which worked for you. Let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Other than above suggestions,

Make sure that "Your Element" that you are looking for is physically visible in your Browser screen. Meaning, if element is not visible , user needs to scroll down in order to see it. Driver behaves similar. In order to prevent "ElementNotVisiable" exception make sure it is also visible on browser page

Try This,

```
Select elm = new Select(driver.findElement(By.Xpath("Your element's Absolute Xpath")));
//Thread.sleep(100);
elm.selectByValue("Dropdown Value which you want to select");
```

Comment: Yes, it is physically available on the screen and manually, I am able to perform all the actions but not through the automation.

Comment: Try to select it by using "Absolute Xpath" of the element,unless you don't have ID of the element. If you are having this problem on a page which angular 4+ is used, you also might try to update selenium version. Also another approach could be waiting until angulars' views are loaded.  If there are more than one view and you cannot detect, try Thread.sleep before you execute Click on element. I hope one of these approaches will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I read answers to your question that should solve your problem. 
But noone asked you (and you did not provide us, in your question) informations   about the version of your **MicrosoftWebDriver**, **Selenium**, and **Browser** that are you using.

From [Microsoft WebDriver download](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/), are you using a version that should be supported from your browser?

From [EdgeHTML issue tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/?page=1&q=ElementNotVisibleException), I found only 2 issues (that are fixed) with key element **ElementNotVisibleException**.

Comment: I am using Selenium 3.5.3 and the version of the Microsoft WebDriver is 4.15063 which matches with the build number of my PC. My PC has a Windows 10 Pro Edition, version is 1703 and OS Build is 15063.674.

Comment: @DG4 and the version of your browser? should be 15.15063

Comment: @DG4 I really think could be a version problem with something (with selenium 3.5.3, if we trust what say Microsoft). Could you try to update your browser at the latest version and try with the latest release of the Microsoft WebDriver? Anyway, if doesn't work, I think there are the extremes to open an issue in their issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases I usually take a screenshot just before the line where exception occurs and save it somewhere to further investigation. Then I mostly have to add a scrollUp()/scrollToVisible() function before this line to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've exactly the same problem with GWT. For any reason there's no way to call click directly.

Workaround that worked for me

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```